# How to Store XML Data in a table in Access 2007 Database

Tags: ms-access

I wish to insert the content of XML data into a ScreenContent column(lets say in table "Screen") . What will be the Datatype of the Column ? I tried "Text" and "Memo". It took only 255 char's.

The actual XML data is about 150000 char's.

The sample of the data is

```
INSERT INTO  ent_Screen (ItemId, [ScreenCode],[ScreenContent]) VALUES ('1','2','<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:v="http://schemas.microsoft.com/visio/2003/SVGExtensions/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="st76" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" contentStyleType="text/css" height="11in" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 1224 792" width="17in" xml:space="preserve" zoomAndPan="disable"><style type="text/css" xml:space="preserve"><![CDATA[ .st1 {fill:#facca7;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2.16} .st2 {fill:#edcdcb;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2.16} .st3 {fill:#d1ebf1;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.24} .st4 {marker-end:url(#mrkr4-16);stroke:#d9680d;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2.16} .st5 {fill:#d9680d;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#d9680d;stroke-opacity:1;stroke- ............................................. </svg>)
```

I am not able to see the whole data in the Access DB.

Please let me know how to print the data.

Thank you,
Ram

Answer (score 1):

Because of so many quotes and / and all kinds of characters, you going to have a rough time using a SQL insert statement in Access sql (especially since there really not a escape charcter or even a third delimiter).

However, if you grabbing and working with this data in code, I would consider using DAO and a recordset. I believe the sql statement is limited to about 4000 chars, and you talking about 150,000.

So I would use DAO, and something like:

```
  Dim rst        As DAO.Recordset

  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ent_Screen")
  rst.AddNew
  rst!ItemId = 1
  rst!ScreenCode = 2
  rst!ScreenContent = strXML

  rst.Update
  rst.Close
```

So, the code solves the issue of delimiters, and it also solves the sql string length limitations issue.